# Cypress custom commands not recognized

Tags: cypress

I want to create a custom login command.  I've added the command to my `commands.js` file, and also have the import command added to `index.js`.

When I create a new test file under my integration folder, I try to reference my new command with `cy.loginWith()`, but it is not recognizing it as a command.

If I add import `../../../support/commands` to the top of my new login spec file, the `cy.loginWith()` custom command is recognized and invoked correctly.
However I know this is not a good thing to do.

This is my custom command in my `commands.js` file:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('loginWith' , (email, password) => {
    cy.get('[name="username"]').type(email)
    cy.get('[name="password"]').type(password)
    cy.get('[name="Login"]').click()
})
```

This is my index.js file:

```
import "./commands.js"
```

This is my `list.js` spec file that sits under `/cypress/integration/clients/client list/lists`:

```
/// <reference types="Cypress" />

import "../../../support/commands"

// login to the app
it('A User logs in and sees a welcome message', () => {
    cy.visit('.../login.cfm')
    cy.loginWith('username', 'password')
    expect(cy.contains('Welcome back!'))

   }
)
```

Is there something I may have misconfigured that is not recognizing the `index.js` file?

Comment: Is the value for `supportFile` in `cypress.json` pointing to your `index.js` file?  If it is not set, have you moved `index.js` from its default location?

Comment: The only thing in my cypress.json is:    { "requestTimeout": 25000}

Comment: is the `index.js` file located at `[project root directory]/cypress/support/index.js`?

Comment: Yes, it is.     Should it be someplace else?

Comment: No, that's the default location, where it should be.  I was checking that it has not been moved - then Cypress wouldn't be able to hook it up.  I am not sure why it can't be found

Comment: I pasted your command into my code and it worked, just the code to add the command.  I did not imports, and it did get there.. I will look further..

Comment: remove the import "../../../support/commands" for giggles, I didn't need it

Comment: My` index` file looks like as following `import './commands'`. Please try removing the `.js` extension from the index file and try restart app again.

Comment: I've tested your custom command, as is, the `import './commands'` with and without the `.js`, and the levels of nesting involved with your test grouping, and successfully executed the test.  Seems like something else is at play...

Comment: What do you get from `console.log(Cypress.config().supportFolder, Cypress.config().supportFile)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted Cypress, and selected the proper project folder and now things are working.  I guess for me, the solution was to make sure you select the correct project folder.  Thanks to all of your suggestions though.

Comment: How did you select correct project folder? What changes you made? I am facing the exact issue.

Comment: When opening up Cypress, I made sure to pick the path of where I have Cypress installed.  After that, I add this to my index.js :import "./commands.js" so I made sure the command.js was up one location above.

Comment: Intelligent Code Completion is different aspect all together from the fact that command is not executing. Reference: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/intelligent-code-completion.html#Writing-Tests

Answer (score 6):

My issue was that intellisense worked fine and everything ran perfectly after doing:

`import '../support/commands';`

My fix was very simple... just add `supportFile` to your `cypress.json`:

```
{
  "supportFile": "cypress/support/index.ts",
  "baseUrl": "http://localhost:3000"
}
```

```
// index.ts
import './commands'
```

Comment: What is in your index.ts? Because I set my supportFile to e2e.ts and imported the commands into there, but it doesn't seem to work. So I still need to import the commands into every testfile

Answer (score 4):

None of the above worked for me, but this worked:

```
    declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable {
      customCommand: typeof customCommand;
    }
  }
}

function customCommand(input: MyCustomClass) {
  // ...
}

Cypress.Commands.add('customCommand', customCommand);
```

got the answer here: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-documentation/issues/2565

Comment: I'm using typescripts and adding the declare global around the namespace fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I'm using typescripts and IntelliJ, adding `declare global` did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Turns out I forgot to prefix the function with cy. Double check to make sure that you are not calling the function with just the name

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, but my cause seems to be different. Nevertheless, I add my problem and solution for those that run into the same issue, as the apparent result is the same error.

I had used IntelliJ compile typescript command, this generates a corresponding companion `commands.js` file next to the source `commands.ts` file. Intellij hides these files in the ui, but you can click on the `>` next to the file to show them.
For some reason the `import './commands'` prefers to load the `commands.js`, which wasn't updated automatically and was missing the function, instead of the `.ts` file. Deleting the companion `.js` file resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but with a different setting, I'm using NX monorepo with many different Cypress 'apps' that share common utilities and libraries in the `/libs` directory and some of these libraries use custom Cypress commands that I have made.
All written in Typescript

My solution was at first to make the external files recognize that they are using Cypress by adding the `/// <reference types="cypress" />` but still my custom command was still not recognized so I referred to [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html#-reference-path-) and found out using `/// <reference path="path/to/your/commands.ts" />` to be very handy and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error, heres the fix:

**place the true value inside brackets**

`Cypress.Commands.add('yourCommand', {prevSubject:(true)}, (subject) => { //cy.wrap(subject) //your code here })`